# ¿Como chequear length en una expresión dentro de ng-if?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Lo que quiero conseguir es length de una expresion en ng-if junto al ng-repeat, si es cero muestra un mensaje de error, el problema que tengo es que el length chequea el ng-repeat no el ng-if os dejo mi simple código:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in posts" ng-if="item.category_id==data.category_id">
<img src="{{item.post_image}}">
<h2>{{item.post_title}}</h2>
</div>

<div ng-show="!posts.length">
No posts found in this category
</div>
```

Controlador:

```
  $scope.categories = "";
  $http.get(config.urlBase+'json/data_categories.php')
    .success(function(data, status, headers,config){
      console.log('Data categories success');
      $scope.data = data.categories[$state.params.id];
      $scope.categories = data.categories;
    })

  $scope.posts = "";
  $http.get(config.urlBase+'json/data_posts.php')
    .success(function(data, status, headers,config){
      console.log('Data posts success');
      $scope.posts = data.posts;    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers,config){
      console.log('Data posts error');
    })
```

Comment: No comprendo, que exactamente te esta fallando? Pudieras explicar mejor tu situacion?

Comment: Quiero contar contar los resultados del ng-if no del ng-repeat si el resultado es cero quiero mostrar un mensaje con ng-show, me explico?

Comment: El mensaje que quieres mostrar el dentro del ng-repeat o es el que ya tienes especificado fuera?

Comment: Lo que necesito exactamente es mostar los posts segun cada categoria, si en dicha categoria no hay ningun post quiero que muestre un mensaje, y esta comprobacion la estoy haciendo con el length.

Comment: [Mira este ejemplo y dime que es lo que quieres hacer](http://jsbin.com/cekurumozo/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: A ver si te lo puedo explicar de otra manera mas clara... como tu ya sabes para hacer un count de los elementos en ng-repeat se utiliza length, pero yo necesito hacer el count del ng-if.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65590/discussion-between-einer-and-anonfidusa).

Comment: Podrias poner unos ejemplos de los arrays que te devuelven esos .php. Para poder hacer algo con lo que puedas trabajar. De todas formas las peticiones que realizas son asíncronas, por lo que podría darse el caso de que la petición de las categorias se resolviera a posteriori de la de post. Lo suyo seria que en una unica peticion te viniera array con todo.

Comment: Te adjunto los enlaces: para los posts https://jsonblob.com/api/856761fb-995e-11e7-aa97-3f1c0798af8e para las categorias https://jsonblob.com/api/6a0821bd-995f-11e7-aa97-515576b384bd gracias